# trouble with addClass to ui-dialog button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Could someone please help me add a class to ui-dialog-buttonset.. I have 2 buttons "add" and "delete" and would like to style each appropriately.

How can I add a class to the button that reads 'Add this item'

```
$dialogContent.dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: "New thing",
            close: function() {
                $dialogContent.dialog("destroy");
                $dialogContent.hide();
                $('#other').stuff("removeUnsavedEvents");
            },

            buttons: {
                'Add this item' : function() {

                    if(client_url.val() == '')
                    {
                        alert('client not selected');
                        $other.stuff("removeUnsavedEvents");
                        $dialogContent.dialog("close");
                        return;
                    }

                            $dialogContent.dialog("close");
                        },
                    });

                    update_stuff_overview();
                }
            }

        }
```

Thanks

Edited to add html from ui-dialog plugin..

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Add this item</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add "new_class" to the button above.

Comment: please post all the HTML, JS that you used in this page.

Comment: There is no HTML to go with this. This alone is adding that particular button which reads 'Add this item'.
The jquery ui-dialog function adds the buttons itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
var button_text = $('#button-id').attr('value');
if(button_text == 'Add this item'){
    $('#button-id').addClass('class_name');
}
```

Comment: Not the answer. This is what the ui-dialog plugin puts into html, I edited my question above*

Answer (score 0):

In the open event of the dialog add this:

```
$(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(1)').addClass('your-class-name');
```

It will style the first button only. If you want to style additional buttons, apply in the same way but change the child number (e.g. 'button:nth-child(2)'). It's how I style my buttons in jQuery 1.9